# Working on a project with several guys - how to achieve it due to changes?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on a project with several developers and I need to systematically inform them about latest changes.

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: You could use a [VCS (version contro system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) such as svn, git, etc

Comment: Hello, yes I thought of it but it is for a small project. I think that it is only solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one solution no matter how big is your project and how many guys are involved in.

It is called [`VCS (version control system)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

I highly recommend you to use service like `GitHub` or `BitBucket` to have access to your code repository from all over the world. You can create a private repo and add your friends as collaborators, so only these people would have access to code.

Hope it will help.